# Homology homomorphism induced by linear isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $F: R^n \rightarrow R^n $ be a linear isomorphism. I'd like to prove that induced homomorphism $H_n(R^n, R^n \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}) \rightarrow  H_n(R^n, R^n \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\})$ is multiplying by 1 (when $det(F)>0$) or by -1 (when $det(F)<0$. Since long exact sequence of pair $(R^n, R^n \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\})$ is natural I get a commutative diagram:
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
0 & \ra{} & H_n(R^n, R^n \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}) & \ra{ \delta} & H_{n-1}(R^n \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}) & \ra{v\rightarrow \frac{v}{||V||}} & H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})  \\
\da{} & & \da{F} & & \da{F} & & \da{L} & &  \\
0 & \ra{} & H_n(R^n, R^n \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}) & \ra{\delta} & H_{n-1}(R^n \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\})  & \ra{v\rightarrow \frac{v}{||V||}} & H_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) & \\
\end{array}
$$

where $L: S^{n-1} \rightarrow S^{n-1} $ 
$$L(v) = \frac{F(v)}{||v||}$$
L is invertible, hence it sends 1 to 1 or -1. $\delta$ is an isomorphism. Additionally, homomorphism induced by a map $ v \rightarrow \frac{v}{||v||} $ is also an isomorphism, since it leaves $n-1$ sphere untouched.  Now, since the above is a commutative diagram, I get that $$(v \rightarrow \frac{v}{||v||} )\circ \delta \circ F$$ is an isomorphism and thus $F(1) = 1 \vee -1$.
How can I move further and deduce that $F(1) $ only depends on $det(F)$?Thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the outset, I would use the fact that both connected components of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf R)$ are path-wise connected, assuming that $n>0$. Hence, it suffices to prove the statement for the identity matrix and the diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}(-1,1,\ldots,1)$. Then you apply your argument to these two maps. For the former you get the identity on $H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$ of course, for the latter you can show with Mayer-Vietoris that you get $-\mathrm{id}$ on $H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$.

Comment: What's the advantage of proving that those components are path- wise connected? I honestly don't see it.Do you suggest showing that a map sending $A \in GL_n(R) $ to its ,,sign" of induced isomorphism $A_{*}: H_n(R_n,R_n \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\})→H_n(R_n,R_n \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\})$ is continuous?

Comment: Well, a continuous path from the identity matrix in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf R)$ to the matrix of $F$, if $\det F>0$, gives you a homotopy between $F$ and the identity map.

Comment: could you please explain how to apply Mayer-Vietoris sequence to prove the -id?